# When is the accepted answer ratio recalculated?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I had a 71% accept ratio, and then I accepted a number of answers, but it stayed at 71%.  When will this get updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/#comment-32274)

> the value is cached heavily so expect
> any change to take hours to appear
> (depends on traffic)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is going to be something that is cached a lot, you may not see any changes except for a few times a day.